# cli or command that convert the CSV file to XLS

Tags: linux, shell-script, rhel

I am searching for tool or CLI that can be download
and by this tool , we can use it to convert CSV file to XLS

any idea from were to get it?

Comment: Not a duplicate.  The other Q. is asking about an *ad hoc* script in `perl`, `awk`, `ksh`, or `bash`.  This Q. is more general and asks about a tool.  It might belong in *SoftwareRequests.SE* however.

Comment: Assuming *file.csv* is comma (ASCII 44) separated, run `unoconv -i FilterOptions=44 -f xls file.csv`, which creates *file.xls*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open the CSV file in your spreadsheet application.  It will helpfully offer to automagically convert it from CSV into its native format.